# Difference between "last" and "for the last time"

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, phrase-usage

What is the difference between *'last'*and *'for the last time'*?

> I don't remember when I went to the cinema ...?

A) last
B) for the last time
C) last time
D) at last

Comment: I think it should be - I don't remember when I last went to the cinema.

Answer (score 4):

- *At last* is used when something happens finally after a long wait:

  > At last, we have gotten something to eat.
- *For the last time* means that you will not do this thing again after this time:

  > For the last time, I am telling you to behave yourself.
- *Last time* is used when you refer to some particular time in the past:

  > The last time this happened, Mark had to pay the price for this mistake.
- *Last* can be used in a variety of ways, see [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/last).

Comment: I'd probably add that _for the last time_ indicates the _intention_ not to do something again after this time - a parent who tells their child to behave themselves is _very likely_ to do so again!